# WordPress Pop Up Plugin - Display on any page

Tags: wordpress, popup

Does anyone know about an easy to use an parmater wordpress plug-in that could display a popup anytime someone access the website. For my [binary option website](http://binaryoptions-broker.co.uk/), i would like to have an automatic popup to warn new visitors about the risks.

Many thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to the 'init' action and there load your popup html:

```
add_action( 'init', 'mypopup' );

function mypopup() {
       // Load my warning html
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. I also heard about Wbounce on another forum. I ll try both and see what is best